# Double the alternative digits in a number and add each digit

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to double alternative digits from a  number and add every digit but its not working in c#

```
int sum=0,r,number;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number");
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (number % 2!= 0)
{
    number = number * 2;
    number++;
}

Console.WriteLine("numbers:" + number);
Console.ReadLine();

while (number!= 0)
{
    r = number % 10;
    number= number/ 10;
    sum = sum + r;
}

Console.WriteLine("sum of digits of the number:" + sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Kindly help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please define "not working" what output do you get? What is your expected output?

Comment: A.k.a [Luhn Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)?

Comment: You're not doubling alternative digits. You're doubling the number and adding 1 if the original number is odd. Then you're summing the digits of the number.

Comment: thank you for sharing that but in that example u have given a string value but its not displaying the output

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Luhn Algorithm` which I have reproduced here for you.
[Luhn Algorithm - C#](http://dotnetfiddle.net/hm8hQn)

Luhn Algorithm uses the last digit (rightmost digit) as a `checksum` digit. Hence in my first iteration I skip it since it's not required in the first parts of the function.

Since the length of a given number can vary, I have used `int a` to check my position and know which number I should double and which I should skip.

Read more about the [Luhn Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) here.

```
using System;
public class Program {
public void Main()
{
    int sum=0,d;
    string  oNum  =  "79927398713";

    int  a  =  0;

    for(int  i  =  oNum.Length-2;  i>=0;i--)
    {
        d  =  Convert.ToInt32(oNum.Substring(i,1));
        if  (a  %  2  ==  0)  d  =  d*2;
        if  (d  >  9)  d  -=  9;
        sum  +=  d;
        a++;
    }

    if  ((10  -  (sum%10))  ==  Convert.ToInt32(oNum.Substring(oNum.Length-1)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid");
    }
    else
{
Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}

    Console.WriteLine("sum of digits of the number:" + sum);
    }
}
```

There are three places where the Console writes a line. And at least two of those are visible for any given number. The line that you wanted, "`sum of digits of the number:`" will always show.

Comment: its not displaying the output

Comment: I have brought the code to this parts here... Update the dotnetfiddle.net with your number and let's see where the error is. dotnetfiddle.net doesn't use prompts.

Answer (score 0):

As StevieB said "You're not doubling alternative digits. You're doubling the number and adding 1 if the original number is odd. Then you're summing the digits of the number."

The following code should work for you. I have not tested it for all possible scenarios so please do so.

Also tweek it a little as per your requirements.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        char[] enteredNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToArray();
        int finalNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < enteredNumber.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)//This condition might need tweeking
            { 
                finalNumber = finalNumber + (Convert.ToInt32(enteredNumber[i].ToString()) * 2);
            }
            else
            {
                finalNumber = finalNumber + Convert.ToInt32(enteredNumber[i].ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(finalNumber);
```

Comment: As much as this is "what" the guys asked for, what he actually needed is the Luhn Algorithm that is used to validate most Credit Cards and Account Numbers.

Comment: Please mark an answer if it helped solve your issue. If you solved it yourself then it is ok.